# Get rid of windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, 32-bit

I picked to install and partition with Windows and Ubuntu 11.10 but now I want to get rid of Windows and just use Ubuntu. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed as a dualboot and let grub install it's bootloader it should be as simple as deleting the windows partition - obviously back up anything you wish to keep. If you have other ntfs partitions, for data for instance, be careful to remove the correct one.

I would also be inclined to burn the w7 repair discs if you have not done so already - just in case.

If you installed as a wubi install then it is not quite as simple - you need to either reinstall ubuntu as a dualboot - not as wubi.

You could try this if it is a wubi install.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F

Comment: And ubuntu will automatically know it can use all the disk space?

Comment: i have the same issue. but: "it should be as simple as deleting the windows partition". - forespiskie, do you mean  formatting the partition that i usually load etc? how would i do that? is there an application in ubuntu for that purpose?